# ERROR: Access is forbidden when trying cloud run service-to-service communication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to implement cloud-run services to service communication.

Aim: service A (frontend) need to call service B (content-api) which is connected to cloud SQL DB.

Implemented using official doc - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

My present setup is as below

- Frontend service config

  - Created a new service account and attached it.
  - Created a serverless VPC connector in the host project and configured it with all traffic through this connector.
  - Ingress is set to allow all traffic
  - Authentication is set to allow unauthenticated invocations
- Content-api config

  - Create another new service account and attached it.
  - Used the same serverless vpc access connector which is in the host project and configured with all traffic through this connector.
  - Ingress is set to allow internal traffic only.
  - Authentication is set to required authentication (frontend service code is fetching token from metadata server and is able to connect using that token)
  - Also configured cloud run invoker role for frontend service account principle in content-api (show info panel settings).

Expecting to get data from content-api when frontend service is triggered.

I'm able to trigger frontend service but getting access forbidden error (guessing due to content-api is set to allow internal ingress only ). But when I change that content-api ingress setting to allow all traffic. It Is working fine - requesting a token and using that to call content-api and which queries DB and responds with the expected value.

what could be the cause for the internal setting error ( Access Forbidden )?  And how to resolve this? Thanks in advance for your answers/suggestions.

Comment: What's your frontend language?

Comment: My frontend is written in PHP just made two curl calls. 1) for metadata server to get token 2) for content-api to fetch from database. And content-api is developed in aspdotnet.

Comment: I don't understand what's happening, when I say allow all traffic for ingress in content-api. Frontend is able to communicate but if i say only internal to content-api it says forbidden even though I attached vpc serverless access connector to both with route all traffic through this connector!!